# How to map strings made up of printable characters to ints

Tags: python

I have downloaded a book from project Gutenberg. For a coding project I need to map each word to a positive integer. The letters in the words are all printable but the full alphabet used is of size 75 for this book.  This includes punctuation.

How can I map each word to an integer?  The same word should always be mapped to the same integer but different words should be mapped to different integers.

The input is a list of words. For example:

```
'[', 'Emma', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen', '1816', ']', 'VOLUME', 'I', 'CHAPTER',...
```

Ideally I would like to avoid reading in the whole input just to map the first word, for instance.

Comment: Use a [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash)?

Comment: @Tomerikoo  Ideally I would like to avoid having to process the entire file in order to map the first word.

Comment: Why would you need to process the whole file? Just `hash` the first word...

Comment: @Tomerikoo ah that sounds interesting. Could you give an answer please?

Comment: @Tomerikoo there could be hash collisions (unlikely, but just hashing is an unclean solution imo)

Comment: @timgeb but it might be good enough.  Are there 32/64 bit hash functions in python? I don't want to end up with a 128 bit integer

Comment: Yep @timgeb this is why I don't post an answer. But it might be a good direction to work on...

Comment: `sum(b*256**i for i,b in enumerate(bytes(word,'utf-8')))` works but can the 256 be reduced as there are only 95 printable characters?

Comment: @Anush you might create order for these 95 and treat words as integers written in base-95 system

Comment: @Daweo great idea. Can you edit this into your answer?

Comment: @Anush there exist 32-bit hash function, it is `zlib.adler32` from [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) built-in module, it returns *unsigned 32-bit integer*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import count

class WordMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self._words = {}
        self._counter = count()
    
    def add(self, word):
        if word not in self._words:
            self._words[word] = next(self._counter) 
    
    def __getitem__(self, word):
        return self._words[word]
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._words)
```

Demo:

```
>>> wm = WordMap()
>>> wm.add('Emma')
>>> wm
{'Emma': 0}
>>> wm.add('test')
>>> wm
{'Emma': 0, 'test': 1}
>>> wm.add('Emma')
>>> wm
{'Emma': 0, 'test': 1}
```

Some tweaks depending on your use case might be in order. For example, you could only add the lowercase version of words to `self._words` if you want a `WordMap` to be case insensitive.

Comment: Well this seems to perfectly stand for all requirements: same word will always map to same number, no two words will share the same number, and this will produce the smallest numbers possible. Oh the only down-side you have to read the whole file

Comment: Actually maybe you don't need to read the whole file either. You get the mapping for the first word as soon as you have read it in.

Comment: @Anush I was thinking of what if you want just the 34th word for example when the mapping is initialized. But still, in a single instance of a program this still ensures the requirements. The values might shift but they will still be unique no matter the order of words you access

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't think the values shift either. I mean once  a word is mapped to an int it keeps that mapping forever.

Comment: @Anush What I meant is that for two different runs of your program, a specific word might have different values depending on the order you read the file. But as I don't know your exact use-case I might be talking nonsense...

Comment: @Tomerikoo You are right but I will always read the file in the same order so that's ok.  I think this is essentially the correct answer.  The only downside is that you use more memory to store the dict.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it following way (if big numbers are not problems), encode it using `ascii` (if your text is limited to ASCII character) or `utf-8` then treat these bytes as integer, i.e.:

```
def get_code(x):
    return int.from_bytes(x.encode('ascii'), 'big')
words = ['[', 'Emma', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen', '1816', ']', 'VOLUME', 'I', 'CHAPTER']
for w in words:
    print(w, get_code(w))
```

output

```
[ 91
Emma 1164799329
by 25209
Jane 1247899237
Austen 71972703987054
1816 825766198
] 93
VOLUME 94898583063877
I 73
CHAPTER 18938268797388114
```

Keep in mind that this method will not yield smallest values possible. Another possibilty if you know all characters in advance is treat them as digits after providing order. Consider simpler example: getting codes for words consisting of uppercase ASCII letters, as there are `26` it means using `base-26` system, so

```
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def get_code(word):
    values = [chars.index(i)+1 for i in word]
    return sum(v*26**inx for inx, v in enumerate(values))
words = ['EMMA', 'BY', 'JANE', 'AUSTEN', 'VOLUME', 'I', 'CHAPTER']
for w in words:
    print(w, get_code(w))
```

output

```
EMMA 26707
BY 652
JANE 97380
AUSTEN 168989055
VOLUME 65725188
I 9
CHAPTER 5629312471
```

You might elect to use different endianess.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer. Given that there are only 95 printable characters, can this be used to reduce the size of the ints?

Comment: Maybe `import string; chars = string.printable` will solve the problem

Comment: My example is contrived for clarity, you might adopt it to any characters by replacing `chars` with string holding all possible characters (every just once) and `26` by length of said string

Comment: Thank you for your answer which is great. I wish I could accept two answers!

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` and `enumerate`:

```
words = ['[', 'Emma', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen', '1816', ']', 'VOLUME', 'I', 'CHAPTER']
{word: idx for idx, word in enumerate(set(words))}
```

You will need to read in the whole input to know all the unique words in your text.

**Edit**

Added removal of punctuation and lowercasing the text.

```
from gutenberg.acquire import load_etext
from gutenberg.cleanup import strip_headers
import string

text = strip_headers(load_etext(158)).strip() # download http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/158
punctuation = string.punctuation + '“”'
text = text.lower().translate(str.maketrans(punctuation, ' ' * len(punctuation))) # strip punctuation 
words = sorted(set(text.split()))
{word: idx for idx, word in enumerate(words)}
```

Output:

```
{'000': 0,
 '10': 1,
 '23rd': 2,
 '24th': 3,
 '26th': 4,
 '28th': 5,
 '7th': 6,
 '8th': 7,
 'a': 8,
 'abbey': 9,
 'abbots': 10,
 'abdy': 11,
 'abhor': 12,
 'abhorred': 13,
 'abide': 14,
 'abilities': 15,
 'able': 16,
 'abode': 17,
 'abolition': 18,
 'abominable': 19,
 'about': 20,
 ...
 'you': 7088,
 'young': 7089,
 'younger': 7090,
 'youngest': 7091,
 'your': 7092,
 'yours': 7093,
 'yourself': 7094,
 'youth': 7095,
 'youthful': 7096,
 'zeal': 7097,
 'zigzags': 7098}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I would like to avoid having to process the entire file in order to map the first word.

Comment: Can these be made positive ints? I definitely will need to be able to handle punctuation too.  Why does your method not handle punctuation?

Comment: I added stripping of punctuation. I can make the ints positive, but then you are not guaranteed any more that they are unique (there is a chance for hash collisions).

Comment: Replaced hash again with my set + enumerate implementation